# Fold or hide Kanban-stage dependent on parameter in context

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

Does anybody have experience with the following problem or any idea how to solve it:

I want to fold or hide specific Kanban-stages dependent on a Boolean parameter in the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution to completely hide kanban stages depending on the context (here: job_id). 
This function from hr.applicant does the trick:

```py
stage_id = fields.Many2one(
    group_expand='_read_group_stage_ids')

@api.model
def _read_group_stage_ids(self, stages, domain, order):
    # retrieve job_id from the context and write the domain: ids + contextual columns (job or default)
    job_id = self._context.get('default_job_id')
    search_domain = [('job_ids', '=', False)]
    if job_id:
        search_domain = ['|', ('job_ids', '=', job_id)] + search_domain
    if stages:
        search_domain = ['|', ('id', 'in', stages.ids)] + search_domain

    stage_ids = stages._search(search_domain, order=order, access_rights_uid=SUPERUSER_ID)
    return stages.browse(stage_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `invisible` attribute and get value from the context.

> invisible="context.get('boolean_field', False)"

JFI, I haven't tried it in kanban fold / hide but this logic works elsewhere. For example, field, span, t, div, qweb template etc.

Answer (score 0):

Stage field is a selection field of Odoo. So you can not display its value base on condition but you can display default at some stage like  **statusbar_visible="stage1,stage2,stage5"**.

Comment: This is only for view_mode "Form", I was talking about view_mode "Kanban".